# "global name 'InvalidToken' is not defined"

Tags: python-2.7, boto3, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to interact with an AWS step function via the `boto` api.

I'm getting a `"global name 'InvalidToken' is not defined"` error from the following:

```
except InvalidToken:
    get_logger().error('stuff')
```

What is invalid about this? How should I go about catching errors thrown by this library?

Comment: Post the stacktrace and relevant code to the stacktrace!

Answer (score -1):

You didn't show the rest of your program. It sounds like an `import` is missing, one that would define e.g. boto.InvalidToken.

edit: apparently the OP is using `import boto3`, implying that `boto3.InvalidToken` would be the relevant identifier. The docs and the github repo don't seem to mention such an identifier.

Comment: Hmm I'm importing `boto3` and `botocore_utils`

Comment: You're making me do a lot of guessing, which isn't helping you. Post your code, please. Looking at https://github.com/boto/boto3/tree/develop/boto3/ I see no "InvalidToken". What made you believe that was something you'd like to catch? Did you use `from boto3 import InvalidToken`? When there is no `try` / `except` in the code, what does a stack trace look like, what exception name does it mention?